# Node.js не находит модуль

Tags: node.js

Решил познакомится с node.js, взял фреймворк express.
Создал свой проект так:

```
$ mkdir project
$ cd project
$ npm init
$ su -c "npm -g install express"
$ mkdir src
$ cd src
$ touch app.js
```

И в app.js написал следуйщие:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Запускаю так `node app.js` и получаю:

```
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/THE-Swank/www/project/app.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Перепробовал разные способы с интернета но все ровно не находит, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

зачем Вы пытаетесь установить `express` глобально?

Замените строчку

```
$ su -c "npm -g install express"
```

На

```
$ npm install express --save
```

Comment: Не надо устанавливать модули npm в локальный каталог от рута. Прям вот совсем не надо

Comment: согласен, тут я что то затупил

Comment: Перед этим ставил локально, в интернете мелькали ответы что надо глобально, вот и попробовал

Comment: @Виталий, нет, express глобально не надо. Совсем.

Comment: Переустановил как локальный и все заработало, спасибо